# Different behaviour of multiple ELF relocations on i386 and x86-64

Tags: x86, linker, x86-64, elf, relocation

Per the [System V gABI](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi4+/ch4.reloc.html),

> If multiple *consecutive* relocation records are applied to the same relocation location (`r_offset`), they are *composed* instead of being applied independently, as described above. By *consecutive*, we mean that the relocation records are contiguous within a single relocation section. By *composed*, we mean that [... i]n all but the first relocation operation of a composed sequence, the addend used is the retained result of the previous relocation operation, rather than that implied by the relocation type.

And indeed, if we compile and link the following assembly file

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
#define R(N) R_X86_64_##N
#else
#define R(N) R_386_##N
#endif

     .globl foo
foo: .int 0
     .reloc foo, R(32), bar
     .reloc foo, R(32), baz
```

and the following C file

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__asm__(
    ".globl bar\n\t"
    "bar = 0x42\n\t"
    ".globl baz\n\t"
    "baz = 0x57"
);

extern unsigned foo;
int main(void) {
    printf("%X\n", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

with a 32-bit x86 GCC targeting Linux, the resulting program outputs 99, so both relocations have indeed been applied. However, with a x86-64 GCC, it outputs 57, that is, only the last relocation has had any effect.

I cannot find anything in the [AMD64 psABI](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/x86-64-ABI/abi.pdf?job=build) that would suggest this behaviour; however, it seems to be consistent over GCC and Clang with `-fuse-ld=bfd`, `gold`, and `lld`.

What’s going on?

Comment: @PeterCordes Nope! The resulting binary does not have any relocations targeting `foo` (only a couple of libc-related ones). And in any case I just used a Musl crosscompiler to make a pair of static binaries and got the same result. So it does seem that three independent linkers do it this way.

Comment: Oh right, silly me, these are object file relocations that *are* resolved statically by the linker.  Using the same ELF relocation types as runtime relocations, but these aren't those.  Hrm, *can* we create an executable and/or shared library that would result in applying multiple relocations at run-time to the same location, so we'd be testing `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`?

Comment: Does anything different happen with full-width `R_X86_64_64` relocations?  Or `R_X86_64_PC32`, where adding the offsets is probably even less likely to be useful than for absolute.  The fact that RIP-relative addressing exists in x86-64 but not i386 might be significant in terms of having different relocation handling code.  (`R_X86_64_32` itself isn't relative, though.)  Either way, it would be surprising if all three linkers chose to deviate from the gABI standard in the same way without that being intentional.